# Jquery not executung show in phone gap app

Tags: jquery, phonegap

I am building a phone gap app, and have a link that is supposed to show a modal.

The pages a built using js/jquery, the link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:Void(0);" class="btn uploadPhotoBtn" data-id="' + id + '" data-user="' + user_id + '" data-name="' + obj.data.group_name + '">Upload Photo</a>
```

Then when clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.uploadPhotoBtn', function () {    
   //show modal....
   showModal('photo-upload');
});
```

And the showModal() function

```
function showModal(id) {
    alert(id);
    $('#' + id).show();
}
```

The alert just before the.show() shows up, but the modal never appears.

Comment: What is `Void(0)`?

Comment: @Taplar https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-javascript-void-0-mean

Comment: `Void` != `void` @Judson  Javascript is case sensative

Comment: @Taplar I have changed that to "void", but still have the same results.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have a `id` attribute on your HTML. You have a `data-id` attribute.

Try this instead:

```
function showModal(id) {
  $('[data-id="'+id+'"]').show();
}
```